# How do I change the color of the spell checker squiggly red line for GTK applications?

Tags: gtk, gedit, geany

For example for Geany and gedit. I expect something as simple as some .gtkrc-2.0 line but there is no documentation on this.

How do I change the color of the spell checker squiggly red line for GTK applications or specifically for Geany and gedit?

Comment: I really doubt there will be a global setting for this. There may be, but that would be surprising. It seems far more likely that each program will have implemented this in its own way.